# How to create mysql database using a form .i am using spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am in training now and I have to create mysql database from a form, where I  have to enter the name of the database and its details, all spring with the boot,

Comment: Your request is rather not specific. Maybe you should point out what you tried so far and what your current issue is.

Answer (score 0):

in first time you need to add thes dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and in the file src/main/resources/application.properties  you will add :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/netgloo_blog
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

good luck